# How to make GWT widget from HTML and javascript?

Tags: java, gwt

I need to make a custom GWT widget from HTML and javascript code. The javascript code should be called on the widget, but the javascript should receive the widget DOM component as a parameter.

Also, the widget's HTML has to be directly dependent on the arguments, given to the widget's constructor.

What is the "idiomatic" way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple. You can start by extending `Widget` class.

To create DOM representation, you need to use `Document.get()` (or other old api depends on what you prefer). 
To call external javascript you will need to use [JSNI](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI).

Also you will have to override `onDetach` and `onAttach` methods, so you can notify external JS when your element is added to dom, and when external JS should perform some  cleanup (if needed).

Example code:

```
public class MyWidget extends Widget{

     public MyWidget(String params) {
         Document document = Document.get();
         DivElement divElement = document.createDiv();
         divElement.setInnerHtml(params);
         setElement(divElement); //important, widget needs to know it's root element
     }


     private static native void doJsMagic(Element element)/*-{ //notifies js about element
         $wnd.doSomething(element);
     }-*/;

     private static native void undoJsMagic(Element element)/*-{ 
        //notifies js that it should do some cleanup (if needed)
        //since it is unaware of GWT widget lifecycle
        $wnd.undoSomething(element)

     }-*/;

     @Override
     public void onAttach() {
        super.onAttach();
        doJsMagic(getElement());
     }

     @Override
     public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        undoJsMagic(getElement());
     }

}
```

Comment: As described at http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomWidgets.html#javascript