# Google+ Sign-In button in GWT

Tags: gwt, google-plus

I would like to use the new [Google+ sign-in button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) with GWT.  I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691624/how-to-make-gwt-widget-from-html-and-javascript)
on how to make a widget from html, but I have not had success yet.

```
public class GooglePlusSignIn extends Widget{

private final String googleHtml="<span id=\"signinButton\">"
+"<span"
+"class=\"g-signin\""
+"data-callback=\"signinCallback\""
+"data-clientid=\"clientID\""
+"data-cookiepolicy=\"single_host_origin\""
+"data-requestvisibleactions=\"http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity\""
+"data-scope=\"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login\">"
+"</span>"
+"</span>";

 public GooglePlusSignIn(String params) {
     Document document = Document.get();
     DivElement divElement = document.createDivElement();
     divElement.setInnerHTML(googleHtml);
     setElement(divElement); //important, widget needs to know it's root element
 }


 private static native void doJsMagic(Element element)/*-{ //notifies js about element
 }-*/;

 private static native void undoJsMagic(Element element)/*-{ 
    //notifies js that it should do some cleanup (if needed)
    //since it is unaware of GWT widget lifecycle

 }-*/;

 @Override
 public void onAttach() {
    super.onAttach();
    doJsMagic(getElement());
 }

 @Override
 public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
//        undoJsMagic(getElement());
     }

}
```

Comment: Hey can put a correct answer to this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to call [`$wnd.gapi.signin.go(element)`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#javascript_api) in `doJsMagic`, but only do it once, on first *attach*. You don't need to do anything in `undoJsMagic`.

Answer (score 1):

You need spaces in your string.  Space between span and class, \"g-signin\" and data-callback, etc.

Also, I'm assuming you know this but you have to replace clientID with your actual client ID from the developers console.